# Erro ao instalar pacote django-auth-ldap e python-ldap

Tags: python, django, openldap

Basicamente estou com um erro ao tentar instalar estes pacotes no python, em ambos os casos o erro é o mesmo, deixo abaixo o erro. Já tentei realizar diversas alterações conforme pesquisas na internet, mas em nenhum dos casos surtiu efeito e o erro permanece.
Estou utilizando o python 3.10 com windows 10 64bits.

Erro:

```
(virtualenv) PS C:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi> pip install django-auth-ldap
Collecting django-auth-ldap
  Using cached django_auth_ldap-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting python-ldap>=3.1
  Using cached python-ldap-3.4.2.tar.gz (378 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=2.2 in c:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from django-auth-ldap) (4.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-auth-ldap) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.4.1 in c:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-auth-ldap) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-auth-ldap) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5 in c:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from python-ldap>=3.1->django-auth-ldap) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in c:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from python-ldap>=3.1->django-auth-ldap) (0.4.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-ldap
  Building wheel for python-ldap (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for python-ldap (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [109 lines of output]
      C:\Users\aislanpaiva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z9ov9twl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:463: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      copying Lib\ldap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\vlv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      copying Lib\ldap\controls\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\controls
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\extop
      copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\extop
      copying Lib\ldap\extop\disconnection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\extop
      copying Lib\ldap\extop\passwd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\extop
      copying Lib\ldap\extop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\extop
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\schema
      copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\schema
      copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\schema
      copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\schema
      copying Lib\ldap\schema\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ldap\schema
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest
      copying Lib\slapdtest\_slapdtest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest
      copying Lib\slapdtest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest
      running egg_info
      writing Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'Doc\.build'
      adding license file 'LICENCE'
      writing manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\aislanpaiva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z9ov9twl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:153: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'slapdtest.certs' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.

  
      !!
 
 
      ############################
      # Package would be ignored #
      ############################
      Python recognizes 'slapdtest.certs' as an importable package,
      but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.
 
      'slapdtest.certs' has been automatically added to the distribution only
      because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
      in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).
 
      Please make sure that 'slapdtest.certs' is included as a package by using
      the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
      (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
      instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
 
      You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
      documentation page.
 
 
  !!
 
    check.warn(importable)
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\README -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gencerts.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gennssdb.sh -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.conf -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\slapdtest\certs
  running build_ext
  building '_ldap' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Modules
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.4.2 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules -IC:\projeto-sistrapi\sistrapi\virtualenv\include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
  LDAPObject.c
  C:\Users\aislanpaiva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jh53yc23\python-ldap_61a97825da94430887188d8c1961e3fc\Modules\common.h(15): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]



 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score -3):

consegue resolver da seguinte forma:
baixei o whell correspondente ao meu sistema no seguinte site: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap)

Para saber qual arquivo é o correto, basta executar o seguinte comando:
pip debug --verbose
ele vai apresentar uma lista de extenções compativeis com o sistema, basta ir no link anterior e baixa a correta e realizar a instalação.

[print do exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBDTS.png)

para realizar a instalação o comando é basicamente:
pip install python_ldap‑3.4.0‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl  (este foi o que no meu caso deu certo)